# How to add a fixed price button to a simple php contact form?

Tags: php, html, stripe-payments

I have a simple php contact form to get a buyer's personal information and address, it is possible to have a 'fixed price' Stripe button act as the submit button?

This would make it possible for me to send my product to the buyer's address whenever I receive a payment in Stripe.

As I have one simple product that I want to sell in a specific country, I need to have the buyer's address. I could use WooCommerce etc. but that's too much for just one product, I want to have a very minimalist solution.

So, instead of a **submit** button it should be a (fixed price) **pay** button and act as both (So, it should also acts as a submit button for the form.), I hope I was able to explain my intention.

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
<p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
<p>address</p> <input type="text" name="address">
<p>city</p> <input type="text" name="city">
<p>Price: €20</p>
<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

By the way, no worries, the page is secured with HTTPS ofcourse :)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow but maybe `<input type="hidden" name="price" value="20">`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the user's details to be sent to you by email and at the same time send the user to Stripe to pay the €20.

Here is what you can do;

**Option A**
- make your HTML form submit to a php script that collects and sends the user's data to you by email, then uses Stripe's php class to do the payment stuffs.

**Option B**
- Use ajax to handle your form. You ajax code should first submit the user's data to a php script that sends them to you by email, then submits payment details to Stripe using their JavaScript API

Note that you will need to collect the user's card details too on the form because stripe api will need them to process the payment